# I have a clickable row that opens a modal, I would like the modal to be populated with the contents of the row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button where I can create a task, the task details get inserted into my database and then I call that database to display the rows on my page. I currently am able to click on a row but only the details of the last row is shown. I ultimately would like to click on a row and then open the modal with all the contents populated.

I have tried the following:

-Tried to move php array into a javascript array and then call the array to try and populate my modal depending on what row is clicked. 
- Tried to follow this idea [Modal Button on each row displays modal which fetch details from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807924/modal-button-on-each-row-displays-modal-which-fetch-details-from-database)
but seems like that would only work if I used a button. 
-I tried moving the end of the while loop bracket because I thought that the second while loop should be nested in the other but that came with worse results.

```
  <table class="taskTable" >
 <tbody class="task-tbody">

            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($Table)){ $task123=$row1[2];  ?>
            <tr class = "task-tr"  onclick="document.getElementById('viewTask').style.display='block'">
                <td class="task-td"><input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[0]=='backlog') {$statuscss= 'statusBacklog';} elseif ($row1[0]== 'inprogress') {$statuscss= 'statusInProgress';} else{ $statuscss= 'statusDone';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?><?php echo $row1[0];?></div></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[1]=='HIGH') {$statuscss= 'priorityHigh';} elseif ($row1[1]== 'MEDIUM') {$statuscss= 'priorityMedium ';} else{ $statuscss= 'priorityLow';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?>  <?php echo $row1[1];?></div></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $task123;?></td>
                <td class="task-description"> <?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[4];?></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[5];?></td>
                <td class="task-td" width="15"> </td>
            </tr>
<?php }?>
    </tbody>
        </table>

        <br><br>

     <div id="viewTask" class="modal" style="display: none;">

        <div class="taskOpenContent">

<?php 

                    $modal123 = "select Tasknumber,Priority,Description,Duedate,Title, Status1 from Universe.Task where Tasknumber=$task123;";

                    $modalqry = mysqli_query($link, $modal123);

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($modalqry))
                        {
                            $Tasknumber_modal=$row[0];
                            $Priority_modal=$row[1];
                            $Description_modal=$row[2];
                            $Duedate_modal=$row[3];
                            $Title_modal=$row[4];   
                            $status_modal=$row[5];
                        ?>


          <div id="editTask">

            <table class="taskTableOpen">
            <tbody class="task-tbodyOpen">

            <tr class="task-tr">
            <td class="task-td"  id="backlogp">  <?php if ($status_modal=='backlog') {$statuscss= 'statusBacklog';} elseif ($status_modal== 'inprogress') {$statuscss= 'statusInProgress';} else{ $statuscss= 'statusDone';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?><?php echo $status_modal?></td>
            <td class="task-td"><?php if ($Priority_modal=='HIGH') {$statuscss= 'priorityHigh';} elseif ($Priority_modal== 'MEDIUM') {$statuscss= 'priorityMedium ';} else{ $statuscss= 'priorityLow';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?>  <?php echo $Priority_modal;?></div></td>
            <td class="task-td"></td>
            <td class="task-td"><?php echo $Duedate_modal?></td>
            <td class="task-td"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></td>
          </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            <h1 id="title" value="swag"><?php echo $Title_modal?> </h1>

            <p id="content" class="taskDescOpen"></p><?php echo $Description_modal;?></div>

        <button type="button" id="editBtn" class="taskEdit">Edit <i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
        <p></p>

          <div class="containerComment">
             <textarea placeholder="Comment..." class="taskComment"/></textarea>
          </div>


          <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('viewTask').style.display='none'" class="closebtn">Close</button>
          </div>


<?php }?>


        </div>

        </div>

        <script>

    var modal = document.getElementById('viewTask');

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#table tr').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if(href) {
            window.location = href;
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I expected each row to display its own content on click.

Comment: Please paste click event jQuery in your Question ?can you please use dataTable & ajax funtionality ??

Comment: There are two ways to display row's data in modal, 1. When user clicks on a row, make an AJAX request and display in modal, 2. Store data in data attribute in JSON format of each row.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I have never used Ajax before so I am unsure of what you are asking but I have added the click even at the end of my code.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make a modal for each record. For doing so, put your modal code in the loop and make the id of modal dynamic. This way is only advisable if number of records are limited.

Refer this :

```
    <table class="taskTable" >
    <tbody class="task-tbody">
            <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($Table)){ $task123=$row1[2];  ?>
            <tr class = "task-tr"  onclick="document.getElementById('viewTask<?php echo $task123?>').style.display='block'">
                <td class="task-td"><input type="checkbox" name="select" value="select"></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[0]=='backlog') {$statuscss= 'statusBacklog';} elseif ($row1[0]== 'inprogress') {$statuscss= 'statusInProgress';} else{ $statuscss= 'statusDone';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?><?php echo $row1[0];?></div></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php if ($row1[1]=='HIGH') {$statuscss= 'priorityHigh';} elseif ($row1[1]== 'MEDIUM') {$statuscss= 'priorityMedium ';} else{ $statuscss= 'priorityLow';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?>  <?php echo $row1[1];?></div></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $task123;?></td>
                <td class="task-description"> <?php echo $row1[3];?></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[4];?></td>
                <td class="task-td"> <?php echo $row1[5];?></td>
                <td class="task-td" width="15"> </td>
            </tr>
<?php }?>
    </tbody>
        </table>

        <br><br>
     <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($Table)){ $task123=$row1[2];  ?>
     <div id="viewTask<?php echo $task123; ?>" class="modal" style="display: none;">
        <div class="taskOpenContent">
            <?php 
                $modal123 = "select Tasknumber,Priority,Description,Duedate,Title, Status1 from Universe.Task where Tasknumber=$task123;";
                $modalqry = mysqli_query($link, $modal123);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($modalqry))
                {
                    $Tasknumber_modal=$row[0];
                    $Priority_modal=$row[1];
                    $Description_modal=$row[2];
                    $Duedate_modal=$row[3];
                    $Title_modal=$row[4];   
                    $status_modal=$row[5];
                ?>
                <div id="editTask">

                    <table class="taskTableOpen">
                    <tbody class="task-tbodyOpen">
                    <tr class="task-tr">
                    <td class="task-td"  id="backlogp">  <?php if ($status_modal=='backlog') {$statuscss= 'statusBacklog';} elseif ($status_modal== 'inprogress') {$statuscss= 'statusInProgress';} else{ $statuscss= 'statusDone';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?><?php echo $status_modal?></td>
                    <td class="task-td"><?php if ($Priority_modal=='HIGH') {$statuscss= 'priorityHigh';} elseif ($Priority_modal== 'MEDIUM') {$statuscss= 'priorityMedium ';} else{ $statuscss= 'priorityLow';}    echo '<div class="',$statuscss,'">';?>  <?php echo $Priority_modal;?></div></td>
                    <td class="task-td"></td>
                    <td class="task-td"><?php echo $Duedate_modal?></td>
                    <td class="task-td"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <h1 id="title" value="swag"><?php echo $Title_modal?> </h1>
                    <p id="content" class="taskDescOpen"></p><?php echo $Description_modal;?></div>
                    <button type="button" id="editBtn" class="taskEdit">Edit <i class="far fa-edit"></i></button>
                    <p></p>
                    <div class="containerComment">
                        <textarea placeholder="Comment..." class="taskComment"/></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <button type="reset" onclick="document.getElementById('viewTask').style.display='none'" class="closebtn">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    <?php }?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <script>
    var modal = document.getElementById('viewTask');
```

Comment: When I tried this, all of task were gone except for one. The modal ends up having the correct stuff but that because only one row is shown.

Comment: I also tried making the modal 'Viewtask' id to add the task123 variable and all the task were outputted but now only the last row is able to be clicked

Comment: have you checked the html code with 'CTRL+U' in browser. Can you see all the modals with different ids ? Also check if all the onclick event is having different id.

Comment: No I have not but are you saying that a new modal will be created for each row of data? But yes I have made sure that the php variable was added to the onclick event.